# Crashlytics timed out during initialization

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

When I run my Android app with Crashlytics, it hangs at startup, and I get a `TimeoutException`.
Then, when I try to crash my app, I get another TimeoutException, with the message `CrashlyticsCore: Failed to execute task`.
The crash doesn't appears on my Firebase console.

I set up Crashlytics Firebase's tutorial, and I do not have a Fabric account.
I also followed this [commit](https://github.com/n8ebel/CrashlyticsSandbox/commit/80bb37b6c84e38e2a3bd3bef1cb005735b61d750), making me add the gms.google-services plugin.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post the code you're using to initialize Crashlytics and the logcat output when the timeout happens?

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today and in my case downgrading from

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4'
```

to

```
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.3'
```

solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem today. 
Downgrading didn't work for me.

Solved by deleting the google-services.json file and reconnecting my app to Firebase again (new google-services.json was generated)