# Firebase Crashlytics only works while deployed via USB

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

The title speaks for itself I think. I can't understand why this happens, but Firebase Crashlytics only logs crashes while the device is plugged in. Please help, as I'm fed up.

**EDIT:** Crashlytics core also throws a TimeoutException

Comment: Could you provide more information? You said firebase only receive crash report if you deploy it via USB, i guess it is development build variant. And firebase doesn't receive crash report when the app is installed with apk? would it be possible that it is different build variant and some wrong if-else statements that did not initialise the fabric?

Comment: [Enabling debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/force-a-crash#enable_debug_mode) might give you some clues.

Comment: Yeah sorry. The question is a bit unclear, hjchin,I mean that crash logging continues to work only while the app is deployed via USB and the device is still plugged in. Once I unplug the USB cable, crash logging no longer happens

Comment: I have also enabled debug mode. Same issue

Comment: perhaps try with other devices and emulator? I think this is a troubleshooting issue, i would suggest eliminate the possibilities one by one and reduce the scope.

found something similar to your issues here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46546724/crashlyticscore-failed-to-execute-task-java-util-concurrent-timeoutexception
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48039580/crashlytics-timed-out-during-initialization

Answer (score 0):

yes you require some real time operations to be done on your application or else update google plugins in your amulator

Comment: Okay fine. When I perform real time operations when the device is not plugged in, however, No crashes still get logged. That is the question.

Comment: Also, google services in my top-level build.gradle is at 4.0.1